# Return only values where creation date and closed date difference is bigger then 3 days

Tags: kql, azure-data-explorer, kusto-explorer

Hey so I'm using KQL to check tickets where the difference between closed date and creation date is higher then 7.
But I have no idea how to do this, I understand I would need to create a new variable for each ticket that would have the number of the difference, but how do I actually do this?
let difference = datediff(Creationdate, closedDate)

?

Any help would be highly appreciated

Don't know how to create a variable for each value and how to filter when the variable has a value bigger then 5

Answer (score 1):

Extending a calculated column can be done using the `extend` operator. Then, you can use the `where` operator to filter on in.

For example:

```
MyTable
| extend diff = closed_date - creation_date
| where diff > 3d
```

or

```
MyTable
| where closed_date - creation_date > 3d
```

Comment: It really was something simple! thank you that worked perfectly